# Calling a java function from C++ via JNI that returns a string

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access the Java method in a C++ application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/992836/how-to-access-the-java-method-in-a-c-application)

Suppose I have a Java class like this :

```
class MyClass
{
  String value = "a string value";

  String getValue()
  {
    return value;
  }
}
```

I've been trying for hours to implement a JNI function that calls a Java function and returns a string.
Could someone show me through a snippet how to call the "getValue" function from a C++ using JNI and obtain a jstring variable with the value of String variable from "MyClass.

// C++

```
jobject result;

jMethodID method_getValue = m_env->GetMethodID(native_object,"getValue","()Ljava/lang/String;");

result = m_env->CallObjectMethod(native_object, method_getValue);
```

Comment: Show us what you've tried and tell us why it isn't acceptable.

Comment: How about showing the C++ side?

Comment: Making your getter public would be a beginning...

Comment: Did you call your C program from Java. JNI must be initiated by the JVM. The C++ program can call java classes, but, it must have been called from Java to begin with.

Comment: @JamesAnderson That's not actually so. The program can initially be a C or C++ program and it can start the JVM itself via the Invocation API. Basically this is all irrelevant to the OP's actual problem.

Answer (score 6):

```
jMethodID method_getValue = m_env->GetMethodID(native_object,"getValue","()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

here, native_object is supposed to be the class definition object (jclass) of MyClass

```
jmethodID GetMethodID(JNIEnv *env, jclass clazz, const char *name, const char *sig);
```

whereas to here:

```
result = m_env->CallObjectMethod(native_object, method_getValue);
```

NativeType CallMethod(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj,
jmethodID methodID, ...);

Your CallObjectMethod expects as first parameter an object from MyClass, no jclass. 
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html

so either one of the calls is wrong here...

probably the getMethodID... you should definitely check for NULL there.

cheers,

Comment: what is native_object?